# PHP optimizing query with foreach function

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, foreach

I have [this](http://codepad.org/5HWT9d11) code here which is working but obviously not useful.

I've come up with [this](http://codepad.org/4gMkHRzA) solution:
But i was getting `Query empty`

---

UPDATE:
This is the working optimization of the code
Cudos to Alex in the comments who helped me. Hope my solution help others too.

```
$postedids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
 foreach ($postedids as $id){

 $columns = array('pickup', 'delivery');

    foreach ($columns as $c){
     $vid = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."id"]));
     $name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."name"]));
     $address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."address"]));
     $city = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."city"]));
     $state = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."state"]));
     $zip = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."zip"]));
     $directions = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."directions"]));
     $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["$c"."$id"."phone"]));
     if($vid!=""){
     $consigneeupdate = "INSERT INTO `consignees` (`consigneeID`, `name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `directions`, `phone`) 
     VALUES ('$vid', '$name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$directions', '$phone')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `name`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$name' ELSE `name` END,
    `address`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$address' ELSE `address` END,
    `city`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$city' ELSE `city` END,
    `state`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$state' ELSE `state` END,
    `zip`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$zip' ELSE `zip` END,
    `directions`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$directions' ELSE `directions` END,
    `phone`= CASE WHEN `consigneeID`='$vid' THEN '$phone' ELSE `phone` END ";
    }else{$consigneeupdate = "";}
    $consignees .= mysql_query($consigneeupdate) or (mysql_error());
    }

 }
```

Comment: Where are you executing the 'prepared' query?

Comment: Do you use mysql_* ? Nways you should query inside the foreach loop. Use debug to display errors.

Comment: `$c.$id` what the heck does dot there mean? ⇐ pls disregard

Comment: @mudasobwa What it does. Appending variable(s)/string(s).

Comment: Your loop gives `deliverypickup10idid`, i don't think you want this.

Comment: I'm using $c.$id so i can get the variables from the arrays 
`"pickup"."1"."id"` for example. The code is executed further down in the page
as `$consignees=mysql_query($consigneeinsertupdate) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: If you execute the `mysql_query` outside the loop, you will get only the last result.

Comment: Putting the mysql_query inside the loop doesn't solve the problem

Comment: That's a thing not solving problem. You should try to `echo` and paste your query in the database see what happens, what error you get.

Comment: Alex you almost had it! `$id = $c.$id."id";` Was returning  wrong value without the `$` and it was duplicating the ID so i changed it to `$vid="$".$c.$id."id"` which returns $pickup1id. Also the the `query` should be inside the loop and looking like this `$consignees .= mysql_query($consigneeupdate) or die (mysql_error());`

Answer (score -2):

```
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$directions', '$phone')
```

Should be

```
VALUES ('".$id."', '".$name."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip."', '".$directions."', '".$phone."')
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help. I'm getting the same `Query was empty`

Comment: Did you check all of the code? Anywhere there is PHP that's how I'd add it in (or with {$var})